# Como rotacionar um conjunto de vértices em torno de um pivô

Tags: c++, sfml

Eu tenho um conjunto de vértices que preciso rotacionar em um ângulo Θ em torno de um pivô, porém quando aplico a transformação os vértices se distorcem. O que está acontecendo de errado? Peguei a fórmula da resposta de uma pergunta similar nesse [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161277/how-to-rotate-a-vertex-around-a-certain-point)

Eis o meu código:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <cmath>
#define PI 3.14159265359f

using namespace std;

sf::VertexArray vertexRotate(sf::VertexArray &toRotate, float theta, sf::Vector2f &pivot);
sf::VertexArray vertexTranslate(sf::VertexArray &toTranslate, float x, float y);

sf::VertexArray vertexRotate(sf::VertexArray &toRotate, float theta, sf::Vector2f &pivot = sf::Vector2f(0,0)) {
    sf::VertexArray vertexCopy(toRotate);
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexCopy.getVertexCount(); i++) {
        vertexCopy[i].position.x = pivot.x + (vertexCopy[i].position.x - pivot.x) * cos(theta) - (vertexCopy[i].position.y - pivot.y) * sin(theta);
        vertexCopy[i].position.y = pivot.y + (vertexCopy[i].position.x - pivot.x) * sin(theta) + (vertexCopy[i].position.y - pivot.y) * cos(theta);
    }
    return vertexCopy;
}

sf::VertexArray vertexTranslate(sf::VertexArray &toTranslate, float x, float y) {
    sf::VertexArray vertexCopy(toTranslate);
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexCopy.getVertexCount(); i++) {
        vertexCopy[i].position.x += x;
        vertexCopy[i].position.y += y;
    }
    return vertexCopy;
}

int main()
{   
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Linear Algebra");
    sf::VertexArray nave(sf::PrimitiveType::Points, 4);
    nave[0].position = sf::Vector2f(100, 100);
    nave[1].position = sf::Vector2f(130, 10);
    nave[2].position = sf::Vector2f(130, 80);
    nave[3].position = sf::Vector2f(160, 100);  

    for (int i = 0; i < nave.getVertexCount(); i++)
        nave[i].color = sf::Color::White;

    sf::Transform t;
    t.rotate(90);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(nave);
        auto nave2 = vertexRotate(nave, PI/2);
        nave2 = vertexTranslate(nave2, 300, 300);
        window.draw(nave2);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considere essas duas linhas do seu código de rotação:

```
vertexCopy[i].position.x = pivot.x + (vertexCopy[i].position.x - pivot.x) * cos(theta) - (vertexCopy[i].position.y - pivot.y) * sin(theta);
vertexCopy[i].position.y = pivot.y + (vertexCopy[i].position.x - pivot.x) * sin(theta) + (vertexCopy[i].position.y - pivot.y) * cos(theta);
```

Na primeira, você altera o valor de `vertexCopy[i].position.x`. Na segunda, você usa `vertexCopy[i].position.x` como sendo a posição X original do seu vértice para calcular a nova posição Y, mas `vertexCopy[i].position.x` não é a posição original, é a posição final, já calculada. O certo é usar o valor antigo para calcular as duas novas coordenadas. O código "correto" é:

```
vertexCopy[i].position.x = pivot.x + (toRotate[i].position.x - pivot.x) * cos(theta) - (toRotate[i].position.y - pivot.y) * sin(theta);
vertexCopy[i].position.y = pivot.y + (toRotate[i].position.x - pivot.x) * sin(theta) + (toRotate[i].position.y - pivot.y) * cos(theta);
```

Correto entre aspas por que esse código vai rotacionar o objeto no sentido horário, enquanto que o convencional é rotacionar no sentido anti-horário. Acontece que a [matriz de rotação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) normalmente usada, que é:

```
| cos θ   -sin θ |
| sin θ    cos θ |
```

supõe um sistema de coordenadas onde o X cresce para a direita, e o Y cresce para cima. Só que no seu código em SFML, o Y cresce para baixo! Isso faz com que faz a rotação fique na direção invertida ao convencional. Para ter uma rotação no sentido anti-horário, como convencional, basta inverter o sentido dos senos (que indica a direção vertical):

```
| cos θ    sin θ |
|-sin θ    cos θ |
```

ou seja:

```
vertexCopy[i].position.x = pivot.x + (toRotate[i].position.x - pivot.x) * cos(theta) + (toRotate[i].position.y - pivot.y) * sin(theta);
vertexCopy[i].position.y = pivot.y - (toRotate[i].position.x - pivot.x) * sin(theta) + (toRotate[i].position.y - pivot.y) * cos(theta);
```

Outra coisa que também é convencional é fazer as rotações entorno do centro dos objetos:

```
auto nave2 = vertexRotate(nave, PI/2, sf::Vector2f(130, 80));
```

em vez de fazer a rotação entorno da origem, como você fez. Sugiro que você crie uma classe que guarde os vértices dos objetos definidos em torno de (0, 0). Somente quando for desenhar, você deve aplicar as transformações e rotações.

Por último, não sei que compilador que você está usando, mas o código seguinte é inválido no C++ padrão:

```
sf::VertexArray vertexRotate(sf::VertexArray &toRotate, float theta, sf::Vector2f &pivot = sf::Vector2f(0,0)) {
```

Em `sf::Vector2f &pivot`, você não pode passar um valor *default* para um parâmetro que é uma referência não-`const`, você estaria construindo uma referência para um objeto temporário. O C++ padrão permite somente referencias `const` para objetos temporários, o que, no caso, estende a vida útil do objeto pela duração da referência:

```
sf::VertexArray vertexRotate(sf::VertexArray &toRotate, float theta, const sf::Vector2f &pivot = sf::Vector2f(0,0)) {
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta clara e objetiva.